# Image isn't being sent to next view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to send an image from one view to another via a segue and display said image in an `UIImageView`.

The following code gets the picture and assigns it to a global `UIImage` variable. *Excuse the graphics code, I've been playing around trying to merge an image and a text field to create a single image:*

```
@IBAction func sendSnap(_ sender: Any) {
    var size = CGSize(width: self.takenImage.size.width, height: self.takenImage.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    let areaSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.takenImage.size.width, height: self.takenImage.size.height)
    self.takenImage.draw(in: areaSize)
    var outputImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    self.finalImage = outputImage
}
```

I then created a segue with an identifier going from a button to the destination controller and handled the data within the prepare func:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showFinal" {
        let lastVC = segue.destination as! TestingViewController
        lastVC.image = self.finalImage
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is for some reason, the `lastVC.image` isn't being assigned with `self.finalImage`.

I've checked the height/width of final image to ensure it's not empty.

Here is my code for `TestingViewController` (destination): 
@IBOutlet weak var displayImage: UIImageView!
    var image: UIImage = UIImage()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.displayImage.image = image
    print(image.size.height) 
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

`image.size.height` is printing 0.0 in the console so I definitely know the image isn't being sent across... but I'm unsure where to go from here?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in preparForSegue to ensure that your condition is being met and your assignment executing - i.e. is that really your segue's ID?

Comment: Also note: all those "self." before your property names are not required in Swift.

Comment: I put a simple print within the segue condition to ensure that the code was being executed. That seems to be fine. Unsure how else to test @AliBeadle

Comment: Can you add the global variables? You can also do `print(self.finalImage)` inside your `prepareForSegue()` to see if the image is not nil

Comment: The first breakpoint to use is on `lastVC.image = self.finalImage` in prepareForSeque. See if you have something for `finalImage`. Go from there putting breakpoints ahead or behind, depending on what you find.

Comment: Ah interesting, `finalImage` width & height = 0.0, must be something in my `sendSnap` function

Comment: Looking at the `sendSnap` method... I've printed `outputImage` to check if thats not null (it isn't). So i'm unsure why setting `self.finalImage = outputImage` isn't working.

Comment: I think I can narrow it down to setting the `outputImage`

Comment: Won't this be `var size = CGSize(width: self.takenImage.size.width, height: self.takenImage.size.height)` 0,0? As before clicking the function there is no image?

Comment: @Rikh i've printed `finalImage` to the log and it's printing the correct output so i know thats not nul. But it's just not getting displayed in the imageview and im unsure why

Comment: Instead of printing...just put a breakpoint after the image is created like on this line `self.finalImage = outputImage`. And then hover your mouse over the variable `outputImage`. You should see an eye icon next to the *i* that prints it to the console. Do you see the image on pressing the eye icon inside the preview?

Comment: Yeh see the image! That's a cool trick though, I didn't realise you could do that. Hmmm, strange!

Comment: Could it possibly be... because I'm using the prepare for segue func, that is getting called before sendSnap is completed?

Comment: That would be my next guess, put breakpoints and check everything!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137854/discussion-between-dipper-and-rikh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have both

```
@IBAction func sendSnap(_ sender: Any) {}
```

*and* a segue assigned to the same button. When you tap the button, the segue is triggered along with prepare() *and* sendSnap() is called. Which one is running first?

A better approach would be to create a "named" segue, then have the button tap call sendSnap(), and at the end of sendSnap() call:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "showFinal", sender: self)
```

Comment: If using `performSegue` can I still assign the image to "theDesiredSegue"?

Comment: Sure - `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {}` will still be called... this just gives you control over the flow of operations.

Comment: Sorry - I should have just used your already-named segue name... the key is to move it off of the button, so you can call it directly.

Comment: Aw right yes that does make a lot more sense. Thanks a lot, works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

1) In the destination View "showFinal" create a reference for your image.

```
var imageDisplay: UIImage? {
  didSet{
        if let image = imageDisplay {
           self.displayImage.image = image
           self.displayImage.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

2) Now send the this value.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "showFinal" {
    let lastVC = segue.destination as! TestingViewController
    lastVC.imageDisplay = self.finalImage
}
```

}